# Recognising complex objects in an image

Tags: image-processing, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I'm going to be more specific about the situation:

I've captured a screenshot from the game DotA. The information I want to get is what objects eg. heroes (also its name, hp, ...), creeps (also which side), towers, etc. is visible in the image and where they are. A problem come from the fact that in DotA 2 many of these object can be viewed from many perspective, so let's reduce the problem and assume that every object have only one orientation. How might this problem be solved quickly enough, that it can recognise all objects in real time at about 30fps? Any help or suggestions is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you have the good flags: CNN for image segmentation. So my point is that for so many different objects from different points of view and scale (because I guess that you can zoom in/out on your heroes/objects), the easiest way (but the heaviest in term of computation) is to build one CNN for each type of object.

But images would help a lot to get a better understanding of the problem.

Comment: As far as i know, CNNs can only determine if an object is present in the image, but not where in image the object in question is located. This is also an information that I would want to extract from the screenshot. Are CNNs actually capable of answering this?

Comment: The CNN will tell you which pixel belong to the object, so it will also give you the position in the image.

Comment: Just to be clear, which solution are you suggesting?

1: First extract interesting objects from the image, then feed each object into CNNs to find out which sort of object they are.
In this case, how can I extract these objects? Since they are not monochromic objects, I don't really know an algorithm that does the job.

2: Feed the whole screenshot into the CNN, the CNN will output where the objects are and what type of object they are.
In this case, I never knew that a CNN that can perform such a task existed. Some more information or links to which would be very helpful. Thanks.

Comment: No. Feed a CNN with patch, for examples 23x23 pixels, plus the label of each patch. Like that you can train your CNN for each type of object.

Comment: I understand now. Thank you very much!